# HTML & CSS, html block size is reducing as making the page small

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I have a problem as following:
[i hope you will get it what is my problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do8cD.png)
and I don't understand why this happens.

[i think the problem is in header and nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxZAa.png)
I thought it is more likely to happen due to pictures but i am very sure that is not because of the logo, because it is on 24px sizes each. Apologize if my English is bad.

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="https://www.samsung.com/us/" target="_blank">
              <img
                src="../src/assets/img/gnb-desktop-120x32.png"
                alt="Samsung"
              />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-9">
          <div class="navlist">
            <ul class="inner">
              <li>
                <button><span>Shop</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>Mobile</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>TV & Audio</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>Appliances</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>Computing</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>Displays</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>Accessories</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>SmartThings</span></button>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="inner">
              <li>
                <button><span>Explore</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>Support</span></button>
              </li>
              <li>
                <button><span>For Business</span></button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <ul class="tools">
            <li>
              <button>
                <span>
                  (search icon)
                </span>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button>
                <span>
                  (shopping icon)
                </span>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li>
              <button>
                <span>
                  (user icon)
                </span>
              </button>
            </li>
            <li class="d-none">
              <button>
                <span>
                  (bars icon)
                </span>
              </button>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you put some of the css code for these elements in your question ?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap? And what **exactly** is the problem you're having? You didn't describe any issues at all and just posted two pictures. What are we supposed to discern from them?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the problem from the picture. Please try to explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the problem. I have remembered that i did change the value of bootstrap container-fluid class. And i commented it out, then it has been solved.

thank you all!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).